# Postgresql JSON Dynamic Expand & Increment

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

Hello guys ive been trying to build an software using postgresql and python.

Basically i want increment and/or dynamically expand the json

example: at first the field will be empty then:

```
#insert (toyota,honda,nissan)

{"toyota":1,
"honda":1,
"nissan":1}

#insert (toyota)

{"toyota":2,
"honda":1,
"nissan":1}

#insert (honda,mitsubitshi)

{"toyota":2,
"honda":2,
"nissan":1,
"mitsubitshi":1}
```

Yes i know it can be done by first retrieving json doing it via python but i dont it that way:
I dont have much experience with postgresql procedure or trigger feature.

Any Help will be apreciated: :-)

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/ - if you use a properly normalized model, this would be as easy as `update x set count = count + 1 where brand = 'toyota';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalized tables would be more performant, however json solution may be quite comfortable using this function:

```
create or replace function add_cars(cars jsonb, variadic car text[])
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
declare
    new_car text;
begin
    foreach new_car in array car loop
        cars = cars || jsonb_build_object(new_car, coalesce(cars->>new_car, '0')::int+ 1);
    end loop;
    return cars;
end $$;
```

Find the full example in [DbFiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4392fac91ae9d8383bd3962eee64989b)

Answer (score 0):

Please check function below. Hopefully it meets your requirement!

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_test(json)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_sql varchar;
BEGIN 

    IF (EXISTS (
            SELECT json_object_keys($1)
            EXCEPT
            SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'your schema' AND table_name = 'test_table'
            )) THEn
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'There is column(s) does not exists on table'; -- Checking structure.
    END IF;

    var_sql := 'Update test_table t SET ' || (SELECT string_agg(CONCAT(t.key, ' = (t.', t.key, ' + ', t.value,')'),', ')  FROM json_each($1) t);

    EXECUTE (var_sql);

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Procedure execution failed

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select "public"."sp_test"('{''user'',''name''}')
                                  ^
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {'...


Time: 0s

## What am i doing wrong

Comment: `{''user'',''name''}`, I don't think this is right format of Json type. 
Try it `select "public"."sp_test"('{"toyota":1,
"honda":1,
"nissan":1}'::json);`